# How can I disable CTRL+ENTER and ALT+S in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'd like to disable the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keyboard shortcuts in Outlook 2007, to avoid accidentally sending incomplete emails.

I've found [instructions for Outlook 2003](http://blogs.technet.com/usefultechnology/archive/2005/08/23/409572.aspx) but they don't seem to work in Outlook 2007.

**How can I disable these shortcuts in Outlook 2007?**

Comment: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/271

Answer (score 6):

I think you're trying to disable CTRL+Enter instead of Alt+Enter.  Here are the instructions:

1. Select "Tools -> Options" from the main menu in Outlook
2. Click the "E-mail Options..." button
3. Click the "Advanced E-mail Options..." button
4. Look at the checkbox at the bottom

EDIT:  For Alt+S, try reading this Technet article to shed some light on disabling shortcut keys:  [Disable user interface items and shortcut keys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179143.aspx).  You'll need to setup a group policy with the appropriate admin template.  If group policy isn't an option, you should be able to edit HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\DisabledShortcutKeysList\ in the registry.

Comment: +1 i was just about to post those exact instructions, they work.

Comment: That disables CTRL+ENTER but not ALT+S

Comment: I edited my post to help guide you in disabling Alt+S.  It doesn't appear to be as straight-forward as disabling CTRL+Enter, but it's doable.

Answer (score 3):

```
!s::Return
```

in autohotkey would disable that key *globally*.
You'll want to put it in a #IfWinActive block, but I don't know what Outlook's class names are, so I can't tell you that.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class [Class Here]
!s::Return
#IfWinActive
```

Use the bundled Window Spy to grab the class and plug it in, and that'll work :)

Comment: this works fine for Windows Mail too, which does not have any hotkey settings. But unfortunately ^enter::return does not have instead any effect on my system (win10).

Answer (score 3):

## Outlook 2013

For future visitors, in outlook 2013 (maybe 2010), the option is at:

- File
- Options
- Mail
- (section) Send Messages
- CTRL + ENTER sends a message

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, but it's a reasonable workaround: [You can delay delivery of all messages in Outlook 2007+](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HP012328171033.aspx).

Comment: You might want to edit your post to say "delay" instead of "disable."  Disabling delivery of all messages in Outlook just sounds a little counter-productive!

Answer (score 0):

These two lines of code inside an AutoHotkey script should do the trick for both Outlook (any version) and Windows Mail, although only first one actually works on my system (Windows 10):

```
!s::Return
^enter:Return
```

! = alt key

^ = control key

Return = do nothing

Another possible solution only for ALT+S Outlook is adding a key in registry:
:

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes
Value name: AltS
Value type: REG_SZ
Value data: 16,83
```