# Disabling keyboard shortcuts in Entourage/Outlook

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, entourage

Is it possible to disable keyboard shortcuts (especially for "Send") in Microsoft Entourage (Mac OS X - <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>) and/or Outlook (Windows - <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Outlook 2007, see ["How can I disable CTRL+ENTER and ALT+S in Outlook 2007?"](https://superuser.com/questions/38375/how-can-i-disable-ctrlenter-and-alts-in-outlook-2007).

Answer (score 3):

I've fought with this for a while and found that what you have to do is to break the original shortcut for "Send".

Go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts. Now add Outlook/Entourage to the list and make sure that "Menu title" states "Send". After that choose whatever cryptic shortcut you are sure you will never accidentally hit.

Note that you have to quit and relaunch Outlook 2011 for the change to take effect.

That did it for me in Outlook 2011.

Cheers!

/Fredrik

Comment: Verified working in Outlook for Mac 2011. Thanks!

Comment: My Draft->Send menu now claims to be cmd-control-option-shift-1, but that doesn't work, and cmd-enter still sends! Grrr Microsoft! (I am running Office 2011 14.4.3)

Comment: Verified working in Outlook for Mac 2015 (15.16). Thank you!