# How to disable the hotkey to send a composing message in Outlook 2012?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotkeys, sendmail

I often accidentally send incomplete emails by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

I want to turn this hotkey off when I'm using Outlook 2012. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/38375/how-can-i-disable-ctrlenter-and-alts-in-outlook-2007

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this link.  It's for Office 2007/2010 but may also apply to 2013 (assuming you mean 2013).  Be sure to backup your registry first!

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/271

**Don’t accidentally send via CTRL+ENTER or ALT+S**

***Sometimes I hit CTRL+ENTER or ALT+S by mistake and off goes the message as it is Outlook’s shorcut for the Send button.
Is there any way I can prevent this from happening?***

Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010
The first time you use CTRL+ENTER in Outlook 2007 or Outlook 2010, you’ll get prompted by a dialog asking how Outlook should respond to the usage of CTRL+ENTER in the future. There are 3 states possible;

Outlook should always send the message (select the box and press Yes).
Outlook should never send the message (select the box and press No).
Outlook should always ask you what to do (do not select the box and choose Yes or No).

Not 2 but 3 choices are available here.

When you’ve chosen for state 1 and want to change it to state 2 or have chosen for state 2 and want to change it to state 1, then you can change the following option;

**Outlook 2007** 
Tools-> Options…-> button E-mail Options…-> button Advanced E-mail Options…-> option: Press CTRL+ENTER to send messages

**Outlook 2010** 
File-> Options-> section Mail-> option group: Send Messages-> option: CTRL + ENTER sends a message
When you’ve chosen for state 1 or 2 and want to change it to state 3, then you’ll have to delete the CtrlEnterSends registry value name or set its value to 2;

Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Outlook\Preferences 
Value name: CtrlEnterSends 
Value type: REG_DWORD 
Value data: 0 = Outlook will not send when pressing CTRL+ENTER
                   1 = Outlook will send when pressing CTRL+ENTER
                   2 = Outlook will prompt you when pressing CTRL+ENTER

When this key is missing, Outlook will behave as if its value was set to 2.

Comment: All is about Ctrl-Enter. How about Alt-S ?

Comment: Agreed. In the link, it gives info for un-mapping ALT-S ... but the info only applies to older versions of Outlook. Would love to disable this in Outlook 2010+.